# How to introduce a binary operation containing an unknown function?

Tags: maple

I need to set up in Maple the following binary operation $*$:
$$\phi(u_1*u_2)=\ln{\left[e^{\phi(u_1)}+e^{\phi(u_2)}\right]}+Q\left[\phi(u_2)-\phi(u_1)\right],$$

where $Q$ can be chosen to be a specific function (linear, polynomial, exponential or any other elementary function) of its input, while $\phi$ is kept the way it is (just "some function of $u$").

The main purpose of this Maple exercise is to check associativity of operation $*$ for various choices of $Q$.

Without $\phi$ (or $\phi$ being an identity map), I think I could check the associativity of $*$ with basic Maple syntax.  But keeping $\phi$ unknown makes it confusing.  Any advice on how to introduce this operation in Maple?

Comment: it seems it may be possible to check associativity of $*$ without introducing $\phi$ by simplifying expressions for $\phi((u_1*u_2)*u_3)$ and $\phi(u_1*(u_2*u_3))$ and then comparing them.  Not sure if this is completely valid way.

Comment: I just tried that in Maple with known example and it is not helpful.  The expressions are large and not simplified.  Is there anyone out there?